# XAMPP/LAMPP launcher shortcut doesn't work Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lamp, xampp

I have lampp installed on both my laptop and desktop. I created a shortcut for it with the following

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=pkexec /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

This file is sitting on my desktop in /home/username/Desktop for both laptop/desktop. When I add it to favorites it works fine on the laptop, but on the desktop I get prompted for the root password and then nothing else happens. I did chmod 777 on both of these so the permissions are rwx for all groups. The only difference is that on my desktop the file is called xampp.desktop and on the laptop it's called xampp-control-center.desktop, but I don't see how that would matter in this case. I don't even see it as a PID on the desktop. It just doesn't do anything. I don't understand what could be wrong with this. Any one have an idea? Please let me know if you need more info, thank you in advance.

edit: worth mentioning, when I launch the shortcut from the desktop it works. If I add it to favorites it won't launch from there and when I move it to /Home/.local/share/applications it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, had to install nautils for it to run. In case someone else has this problem trying doing

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```